# can't open rstudio in linux debian wheezy error 'GLIBC_2.14' not found

Tags: software-installation, package-management, libraries, r

I get the following error when trying to run `rstudio` on my Debian:

```
rstudio: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by rstudio)
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled `R` and `Rstudio` many times but I only get `R`running but not `Rstudio`. I also have upgraded `lib6` and `lib6-dev` as proposed in other posts.

EDIT: I am using the latest version of `Rstudio` so I do not think that there is another version using a newest version (other than `GLIBC_2.14`)
The output of `dpkg -l | grep -P '(-| )libc-'`:

```
ii  libc-bin                              2.13-38+deb7u8                     amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: Binaries
ii  libc-dev-bin                          2.13-38+deb7u8                     amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: Development binaries
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                  3.2.68-1+deb7u1                    amd64        Linux support headers for userspace development
```

EDIT2: Just to clarify my version `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
Release:    7.8
Codename:   wheezy
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `dpkg -l | grep -P  '(-| )libc-'`. The error suggests that `rstudio` needs libc version 2.14 and you have another one. 2.14 is relatively old, you probably have a newer one. I suggest trying to find a version of rstudio written for your version of libc.

Comment: @ terdon many thanks for your help. I have installed the latest version of `Rstudio`. I see however that have version `2.13`??

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. What Debian are you using? Stable? I have version 2.19-18 on my testing.

Comment: @terdon yes, I'm using stable. I found a workaround on the web. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Where did you get rstudio from? It isn't in Debian. Regardless, you could (most likely) rebuild the sources on Wheezy.

Comment: @ Faheem Mitha from `www.rstudio.com`.

Comment: Ok, but could you be more specific about what version you used and how you installed it?

Comment: @ Faheem Mitha Sorry, I'm using `RStudio 0.99.441 - Ubuntu 12.04+/Debian 8+ (64-bit)`

Comment: Ok. That version is for Debian 8 (Jessie), not for wheezy.

Comment: @ Faheem Mitha Thanks I just realized it. I'm looking for a previous version.

Comment: @terdon and I are confused. Can you hop into chat for a few minutes so we can clarify? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24296/discussion-between-ap13-and-faheem-mitha).

Comment: Let's use the main chat room (if you want to). :-)

Comment: @nopeva Have you found any acceptable answer or any other workaround?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the new features in RStudio 0.99, just use RStudio 0.98: http://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-0.98.1103-amd64.deb .  If you are new to Linux, you should not blindly upgrade your system to Debian Jessie.  And you definitely should not mix oldstable (Wheezy) with testing (Stretch) as one poster suggests.  This will cause loads of problems.  Either use RStudio 0.99 on a new Debian Jessie system, or use RStudio 0.98 on Debian Wheezy.